# Disable IPython Exit Confirmation

Tags: python, ipython

It's really irritating that every time I type `exit()`, I get prompted with a confirmation to exit; of course I want to exit! Otherwise, I would not have written `exit()`!!!

Is there a way to override IPython's default behaviour to make it exit without a prompt?

Comment: If you want to upgrade to IPython 0.11, `exit` doesn't ask for confirmation. (Ctrl-d still does prompt, in case you hit it accidentally)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

If you also want `Ctrl-D` to exit without confirmation, in IPython 0.11, add `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.confirm_exit = False` to your config file *.

If you don't have a config file yet, run `ipython profile create` to create one.

Note [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17078) if you're working within the Django shell.

---

* The config file is located at: `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

Comment: The config is located at `$IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/ipython_config.py` for people who have set this environment variable

Comment: To change the banner (which is quite verbose), add : "config.TerminalInteractiveShell.banner1 = 'Welcome to the ipython shell ...\n'" to ipython_config.py

Answer (score 47):

In ipython version 0.11 or higher,

1. Run with `--no-confirm-exit` OR
2. Exit via 'exit' instead of control-D OR
3. Make sure the directory exists (or run `ipython profile create` to create it) and add these lines to $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py:

   ```
   c = get_config()

   c.TerminalInteractiveShell.confirm_exit = False
   ```

Comment: `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` is preferred in Linux to match freedesktop.org. Works on 1.2.1.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功, with 3.2.1 it isn't - this version even prints `usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:291: UserWarning:
Ignoring ~/.config/ipython in favour of ~/.ipython.` and in the code `We have decided to go back to using .ipython everywhere`. Apparently they changed it in some 1.x version.

Comment: re 1. `alias ipython="ipython --no-confirm-exit --no-banner"` has become my preferred way to launch ipython

Answer (score 19):

just type `Exit`, with capital `E`.

Alternatively, start IPython with:

```
$ ipython -noconfirm_exit
```

Or for newer versions of IPython:

```
$ ipython --no-confirm-exit
```

Comment: @Brendan, as to making it permanent, you can also set it up in your `ipythonrc` profile: `confirm_exit 0`

Comment: Nice, set that with an alias and job done. No messing about creating profiles or changing config.

Answer (score 5):

I like the config suggestions, but until I learned them I've started using "Quit" key combination.

```
Ctrl+\
```

or

```
Ctrl+4
```

This just kills what is running. No time to ask questions on confirmation.

Comment: this is not a good practice, this make kernel send `SIGQUIT` to ipython, left no chance for ipython process to clean up itself.

Comment: e.g. it breaks `sudo` on my machine by changing `stty`'s output